# Group Homomorphism: Is it required to have the inverse preservation to prove Identity Mappings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider two Groups $\left(G,\cdot\right)$ and $\left(H,\times\right)$

And let $f$ be a function $f:G\rightarrow H$

Then $f$ is a Group Homomorphism if $\forall g_{1}, g_{2} \in G$ we have

$f\left(g_{1} \cdot g_{2}\right) = f\left(g_{1}\right) \times f\left(g_{2}\right)$

and that the inverse of $G$ is preserved, i.e.

$f\left(g_{1}^{-1}\right) = f\left(g_{1}\right)^{-1}$

In the textbook I'm reading this is essential so that the identity for $G$ here $1_{G}$ maps onto the identity of $H$ here $1_{H}$ .

This is illustrated simply with

$f\left(g_{1} \cdot g_{1}^{-1}\right) = f\left(1_{G}\right) =  f\left(g_{1}\right) \times f\left(g_{1}^{-1}\right) = f\left(g_{1}\right) \times f\left(g_{1}\right)^{-1} = 1_{H}$

And so,

$f\left(1_{G}\right) = 1_{H}$

I however went about it differently (I'm sure I'm missing something) though and I was wondering if people could have a look over and see if what I've done is valid and if not where I went wrong.

So my method was

$f\left(1_{G}\cdot 1_{G}\right) = f\left(1_{G}\right) = f\left(1_{G}\right) \times f\left(1_{G}\right)$

And so

$f\left(1_{G}\right)^{-1} \times f\left(1_{G}\right) = f\left(1_{G}\right)^{-1} \times f\left(1_{G}\right) \times f\left(1_{G}\right)$

$1_{H} = 1_{H} \times f\left(1_{G}\right) = f\left(1_{G}\right)$

And so

$1_{H} = f\left(1_{G}\right)$

Is this valid? as in can we show that the identity of $G$ maps to the identity of $H$ without having to impose the inverse requirement as before?

Thanks

Comment: The basic property $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ also implies $f(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1}$. In theory development, it can be cleaner to adopt a minimal definition, and use lemmas to get useful additional properties. In textbooks, though, there is often redundancy, for clarity's sake.

Comment: As an aside, the notion of "group" is more naturally described as having three structure operations: a constant (the identity), a unary operation (inverses), and a binary operation (the product). $(G, \cdot)$ is better described as a *semigroup*, and that you are considering a *semigroup* with the extra property of having identity and inverses. A $\cdot$-preserving map is a *semigroup* homomorphism, but a group homomorphism should preserve identities and inverses too. It is a strange feature that these two different structures turn out to be basically the same.

Comment: For an example of how things go awry, consider the relation between monoids and semigroups; monoids are not merely semigroups with identity; e.g. not all semigroup homomorphisms between semigroups with identity are actually monoid homomorphisms.

Comment: @Hurkyl - I didn't realise that a unary operator to defined inverses was required. In all definitions I've read so far (and it's limited I'm very new to this) it merely states that inverse elements exists as opposed to required a unary function to map each element to it's inverse. 

Can you then have say two groups that are identical in their definitions outside of the inverse unary function? i.e. can there be more than one inverse function?

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks correct. It's a fact that a group homomorphism preserves the identity element.

Comment: Indeed, it was just that all the proofs of identity mapping that I observed used the preservation of inverses to illustrate it.
I suppose doing it with the preservation of identity mapping does kill two birds with one stone, but still nice it can be shown without it. 

Also gives it more 'strength' so to speak :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right and you proved correctly that if $f\colon G\longrightarrow H$ is such that $(\forall g_1,g_2\in G):f(g_1g_2)=f(g_1)f(g_2)$, then $f(1_G)=1_H$.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried as most of the illustrations I'd seen online required the preservation of the inverse in order for the identity mapping to be shown. I'm very happy I was able to do it a different way! 
Thanks for looking over.